# how to disable tabpages C# and botton next until all the textbox and all is filled?

Tags: c#

Hello I am developing an application in C#, my application has 1 tabcontrol (5tabpages), what I want to do is disable the next tabPage , and all of them and the button next and before until all the current tabPage is filled in all fields. Very apreciated the answers

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Windows Forms app? If so, try attaching a handler to the TextChanged event of each TextBox on the tab control. When one changes, examine them all, and if they all have data to your satisfaction, enable the next tab and the Next button.

In ASP.NET, you can do something similar with JavaScript using the OnChange client-side event.